# WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw and Unable to capture screenshot while rendering long page using ChromeDriver Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

Using Selenium Web driver with Python, I am capturing screenshot from a page which is very long. Getting the following error. Normally, I got any page's screenshots without any problem.

```
[1112/102333.244:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102333.296:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102333.305:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102337.235:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102337.237:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102337.241:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102337.243:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102357.562:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102357.572:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102357.585:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102357.587:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102358.050:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102358.053:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102358.058:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102358.060:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102429.223:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102429.225:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102430.153:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102430.156:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102430.158:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102430.169:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102430.170:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102503.275:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
[1112/102503.278:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw    

Traceback (most recent call last): in get_screenshot_as_file
  File "page-screen-shooter.py", line 101, in <module>
    driver.save_screenshot(screen_shot_save_location + "{0}.png".format(i+1))           , in get_screenshot_as_png
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1055, in save_screenshot
    return self.get_screenshot_as_file(filename)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1032, in get_screenshot_as_file
    png = self.get_screenshot_as_png()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1064, in get_screenshot_as_png
    return base64.b64decode(self.get_screenshot_as_base64().encode('ascii'))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1074, in get_screenshot_as_base64
    return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 1.789
  (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.97)
```

In my code, I have following options:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
```

I removed the following option.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
```

However I got another error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Unable to capture screenshot"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.97)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
[1112/102333.244:ERROR:tile_manager.cc(779)] WARNING: tile memory limits exceeded, some content may not draw
.
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 1.789
    (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.97)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to unable to capture screenshot of the **WebBrowser** i.e. **chrome=78.0.3904.97**.

---

As per the error trace logs though it is evident that you are using **chrome=78.0.3904.97** but we are unsure about the *ChromeDriver* version.

Now as per the discussion [Issue 1893: java.lang.AssertionError: unknown error: unhandled inspector error](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1893) the error:

```
unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Unable to capture screenshot"}
```

was a known issue with capturing screenshot on Windows which was discussed within [Issue 1844: Chrome 59 remote desktop chromedriver.exe saves white/blank screenshots](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1844) and was addressed through **Chrome v60.0.3112.40**.

---

### Solution

The simplest solution would be to ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v78.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 78.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v78.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/notes.txt))

---

### Outro

[Issue 792: Android Emulator - Unable to capture screenshot](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=792)